# Using two functions to create the average

Tags: python

this code is supposed to take in a file with four index in each line and return the first and last indexs in a dictionary the the if-statement is fulfilled, and it works.The output might be: {1:[2,4,3], 3:[5,6,1]}

```
def value(filename):
   f=open(filename,'r') *
   bat_val=defaultdict(list)
   for line in f:
       four_vals = (line.split(','))
       batch=four_vals[0]
       x=float(four_vals[1])
       y=float(four_vals[2])
       circle = x**2 + y**2
       if circle <= 1:
           value = four_vals[3]
           bat_val[batch].append(value.strip())
f.close()
return bat_val
```

print(value('sample2.txt'))
#Then I want to use the def value()-function in the function below to calculate the average for each key. If i got the output above i will now in this function get:
{1:3, 3:4}

```
 def mean(file):
   calc=value(open(file,'r') )
   result={}
   for bat,val in sorted(calc.items()):
      mean = (sum(val))/len(val)
      result[bat]=mean
      return result
 print(mean('sample4.txt'))
```

#but the function def value() says TypeError in line 12 (marked with *) and I dont understand why

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues.
1- You need to append number to your dict's values since you'll use them to calculate mean

```
if circle <= 1:
    value = float(four_vals[3].strip())
    bat_val[batch].append(value)
```

if you don't want to do this, you can cast values to float before calculating mean in the mean function.

2- And as mentioned in the other answer, you should avoid opening file twice by replacing

```
calc=value(open(file,'r') )
```

with

```
calc=value(file)
```

Comment: The first code is supposed to take in a file with four index in each line and return the first and last indexs in a dictionary the the if-statement is fulfilled, and it works.The output might be:
{1:[2,4,3], 3:[5,6,1]}.                                                                                                                 Then I want to use the def value()-function in the function below to calculate the average for each key. If i got the output above i will now in this function get:
{1:3, 3:4}

Comment: Sorry my first take was way wrong. I updated my answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you open the file twice
once in mean and again in value
try to pass the filename in mean:

```
def mean(file):
    calc=value(file) # <<<<< this line changed
    result={}
    for bat,val in sorted(calc.items()):
        mean = (sum(val))/len(val)
        result[bat]=mean
        return result
```

Comment: mean = sum(val)/len(val)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', I got this as an error message